# remove rectangular border from button

Tags: java, swing, button, border, transparency

Is there a way to remove the rectangular border under the button?

I wish to make it transparent, is it possible?

Here is the image:

[image]

Comment: See [Removing space around buttons in GridBagLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32540954/418556) for ways to make buttons (effectively) invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this code segment, where `b` is the instance of your JButton.

For only remove rectangular border just use

```
 b.setBorderPainted(false);
```

To make button transparent:

```
b.setOpaque(false);
b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
b.setBorderPainted(false);
```

Also remove Painted focus add this

```
b.setFocusPainted(false);
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work, all it does is remove the button layout, but its background still remains visible, please note that i do not want to hide the button, i want to see it but not with that ugly rectangle behind it

Comment: (1+) @FrancescoRizzi, Start by just using the setOpaque(false). This will get rid of the background color outside the border of the button. You can try adding in the other methods one at a time if you still have a problem (although I didn't need them). Otherwise, post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) every time you post a question so we don't have to guess what code you are using or what LAF you are using.

Comment: Solved, it was just a problem with the panel containing the button, still thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following code to remove border:

```
yourbutton.setBorderPainted(false);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work :(
all it does is remove the button layout, but its background still remains visible, please note that i do not want to hide the button, i want to see it but not with that ugly rectangle behind it